# Index was out limits datagridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem with populating a `DataGridView` using my Access database in VB.NET; here is the code:

```
Sub loadcreadit()    
    Try
        DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DBConnect().selectdata("SELECT  items.ClientName, items.ClientAddress, items.ClientPhone, items.ClientCredit FROM items;")
        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
            DataGridView1(0, i).Value = i + 1
            DataGridView1(1, i).Value = dt.Rows(i)(0).ToString
            DataGridView1(2, i).Value = dt.Rows(i)(1).ToString
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    End Sub
```

When I click on button I get an exception is thrown with an error message:

> L'index était hors limites.Il ne doit pas ètre négatif et doit étre inferieur à la taille de la collection. Non du paramètre : index **(Translated) Index was out limits. It cannot be negative and must be smaller than the size of the collection. No parameter : index**

Comment: Translation to English please!!!!!!

Comment: Index was out limites.Il does not permissible to negative and must be inferior to the size of the collection. No parameter : index

Comment: Put a breakpoint and look at the size of the array where you have the error. You'll notice that you are trying to access an item that is out of bound.

Comment: Any reason you're not binding the DataTable directly to the DataGridView via the DataSource ?

Comment: Perhaps `dt` has no rows. But like Andrew suggested, you should instead just set `DataGridView1.DataSource = dt` and then you don't need to check if `dt` is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the data in the `DataGridView1.Rows.Add` method and make sure that you have 3 columns:

```
Sub loadcreadit()
    Try
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DBConnect().selectdata( _
              "SELECT ClientName, ClientAddress, ClientPhone, ClientCredit FROM items;")
        ' make sure you have at least 3 columns
        DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(i + 1, dt.Rows(i)(0), dt.Rows(i)(1))
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: I have an error : **Error 1 Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Add' accepts this number of arguments** in code `DataGridView1.Columns.Add()`

Comment: I forgot that the columns need names like `DataGridView1.Columns.Add("columnName", "headerText")`. You can accept it as an answer if it solves your problem http://stackoverflow.com/tour